# Is there any way to leave the log regarding which file was compressed at alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Is there any way to leave the log regarding which file was compressed at alfresco?
This is the route I know that can compress the file.

1. when using CIFS
2. When clicking the downloads as zip button

Comment: did not get you.can you please explain little more.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can override class `CreateDownloadArchiveAction` (by overriding bean with id `createDownloadArchiveAction`). And then in method `createDownload` you can implement your logging logic.